# Make custom image slider full-width

Tags: html, css, angular

I currently have the custom image slider from this course rebuilt in my project.

https://monsterlessons-academy.com/posts/angular-slider-build-angular-carousel-from-scratch-tutorial

(At the bottom of the article is also a link to the source code on GitHub.)

As you can see in the example in the tutorial, the slider is centered on the page.

**I would like to insert the slider in full width of the page and automatically adjust the height proportionally to the width.**
However, it should not serve as the background of the page. Just an element that uses the full width.

In my opinion, there are two places where changes could be considered:

1. Outside the SlideComponent - in the parent component:

```
 <div style="width: 500px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto">
  <image-slider [slides]="slides"></image-slider>
</div>
```

2. Or inside the imageSlider.component.css

```
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.